# Winjs Promise Async test

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I m developping a Winjs/HTML windows Store application .
 I have to do some tests every period of time so let's me explain my need.
when i navigate to my specific page , I have to test (without a specific time in advance=loop)
So when my condition is verified it Will render a Flyout(Popup) and then exit from the Promise.  (Set time out need a specific time but i need to verify periodically  )
I read the msdn but i can't fullfill this goal .
If someone has an idea how to do it , i will be thankful.
Every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` can be used.

```
var timerId = setInternal(function ()
{
    // do you work.
}, 2000); // timer event every 2s

// invoke this when timer needs to be stopped or you move out of the page; that is unload() method
clearInternal(timerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling at specific intervals, you should check if you can't adapt your code to use events or databinding instead.

In WinJS you can use databinding to bind input values to a view model and then check in its setter functions if your condition has been fulfilled.

Generally speaking, `setInterval` et al should be avoided for anything that's not really time-related domain logic (clocks, countdowns, timeouts or such). Of course there are situations when there's no other way (like polling remote services), so this may not apply to your situation at hand.